# How to create link from an Array changes with every click in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to create a link that adds +1 to an array so that next item in array will be clickable after click.Array is ok but link logic is not working, it stops after no:1.(trying to solve without JS)

```
   $dbc = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $pass, $dbname) or die('connect failed');
        $r= mysqli_query ($dbc, "select url from urllist order by id desc ")or die('query failed');
        $url = array();
        while($set = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
        $url[] = $set['url'];
        }
        if ($_GET ['no'] == 1){
            $no = $no+1;
        } 
        else {
            $no=0;
        }
        ?>

    <body style="background-color: lightgray;margin: 0px">
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="menuin" style="float:left"><a href="index.php">Home</a></div>
                <div class="menuin" style="float:right"><a href="site.php?$no=$no+1">NEXT</a></div>
                </div>
<div>
    <object name="main" data= 'http://<?php echo $url[$no] ?>'></object>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $pass, $dbname) or die('connect failed');
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, "select url from urllist order by id desc ") or die('query failed');
$url = array();
while ($set = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    $url[] = $set['url'];
}
$no = 0;
if (!empty($_GET ['no'])) {
    $no = $_GET ['no'];
}
?>

<body style="background-color: lightgray;margin: 0px">
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menuin" style="float:left"><a href="index.php">Home</a></div>
    <div class="menuin" style="float:right"><a href="site.php?no=<?= $no + 1 ?>">NEXT</a></div>
</div>
<div>
    <object name="main" data='http://<?php echo $url[$no] ?>'></object>
</div>
```

What the code above does is to get the number from $_GET if it is set. Otherwise, it defaults to 0.
Then, the link to the next record is created using the number + 1.
You created the link this way: `a href="site.php?$no=$no+1">NEXT</a>`. You need to output the number with php using the `<?=` shortcode or the echo function. And the first $ is not required.